# Webpage displays small on mobile device

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have developed a website for a charity using ASP.NET and SQL Server. The webpages were developed and tested on a PC (I know now.) The pages appear tiny on mobile devices and most users will be on phones. I used HTML years ago, but am new to CSS and "Responsive Design" ideas. I have read numerous articles about browser detection, responsive design, CSS, Javascript, @Media queries, etc:

I have tried several different approaches, but none have worked for me.

Below is the HTML for one of the pages and screenshots showing the current and desired (simply zoomed in) appearance.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="mysite.logon" %>

<!DOCTYPE html

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
    }
    .blank_row   
    { 
       height: 5px;
    }
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="login" runat="server">
<div>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
              <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="XX-Large"
                  CssClass="StrongText"></asp:Label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="blank_row">
        <td colspan="4"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="25%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
          <div style="text-align:right">
            <asp:Label Text="Email:  " runat="server"/>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="25%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
          <div style="text-align:right">
            <asp:Label Text="Password:  " runat="server" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td width="25%">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
        </td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            <asp:Button Text="Login" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="blank_row">
        <td colspan="4"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="ForgotPassword" runat="server" Text="Forgot password" NavigateUrl="~/ForgotPassword.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
             <asp:HyperLink ID="CreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Create account" NavigateUrl="~/Account.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

https://imgtr.ee/image/MobileSizing.2CUxv

Comment: Here are some things I have tried: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application>  
<https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php>  
<https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media>  
<https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile-using-media-query/>  
<https://www.devicedetection.com/>  
<https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-page-width-height/>  
<https://dev.to/ozanbolel/fit-your-website-to-the-viewport-on-mobile-38hl>

Comment: Change 'max-width' to 'min-width' on '.image-viewer-container img' and remove the height css from the image. That should get you close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your viewport meta tag to this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

[Further reading](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)